# How do we construct a continuous function on the interval $(0, 1]$ without a minimum or a maximum?

Tags: calculus, extreme-value-theorem

One of my Calculus lecture videos poses the following challenge (shortly after an exposition of the Extreme Value Theorem):

> Construct a function $f$ such that
>
> - $f$ is continuous on $(0, 1]$
> - $f$ does not have a maximum on $(0, 1]$.
> - $f$ does not have a minimum on $(0, 1]$.

After some thinking, I came up with the following function $f$, but on further thought I don't think it meets the requirements, because it's not continuous on its domain.

[image]

Does anyone know how to do it?

Solution or hints are both welcome (I'm not being graded for this)

Comment: how about $\dfrac1x \sin(\dfrac1x)?$

Comment: Do you mean absolute or relative max and min?

Comment: @ajotatxe Absolute, I believe

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your idea is right. You want a $\sin$ curve that oscillates  with increasingly narrow high peaks and low valleys.

The question asks for the open end at $0$, which makes things easier. Just use
$$
\frac{\sin (1/x)}{x}.
$$

Answer (score 2):

The number $1$ does not belong to the domain of your function, but you can take$$\begin{array}{rccc}f\colon&(0,1]&\longrightarrow&\mathbb R\\&x&\mapsto&\frac1x\cos\left(\frac1x\right).\end{array}$$It is continuous. It has no maximum, because if $x=\frac1{n\pi}$, with $n$ even, then $f(x)=n\pi$. And it has no minimum, because if $x=\frac1{n\pi}$ with $n$ odd, then $f(x)=-n\pi$.